# How to upgrade openssl 1.1.0e to openssl fips 2.0.x version in linux?

Tags: openssl, fips

I am working with legacy code of a Broker that has 1.1.0e openssl version. I have to integrate a FIPS compliant openssl library to the Broker. So I have downloaded "openssl-fips-2.0.16" from [OpenSSL web site](https://www.openssl.org/source/) . When I check the size of 2.0.16 version, I have been in doubt because the 1.1.0e size is nearly 5 times bigger. My questions are;

- Is it enough to change the libs instead of one another?
- If not, how to upgrade openssl 1.1.0e to openssl fips 2.0.x version in linux?

I am newbie at security, many thanks for your helps from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it enough to change the libs instead of one another?

The `openssl-fips-2.0.16` is not a FIPS certified version of OpenSSL but the FIPS module which need to be used together with the OpenSSL source code. In other words: this is not a replacement for OpenSSL.

> how to upgrade openssl 1.1.0e to openssl fips 2.0.x version in linux?

From [the documentation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/FIPS_modules):

*The 2.0 FIPS module is compatible with OpenSSL **releases 1.0.1 and 1.0.2, and no others**. The extensive internal structural changes for OpenSSL 1.1 preclude the use of the 2.0 FIPS module with that release.*

Thus, no way to use the current FIPS module with your OpenSSL 1.1.0e.

Comment: Thank you so much @SteffenUllrich , your answer changed my perspective to solution. According to **OpenSSL FIPS Guide**   " *If the original
distribution is modified, or if anything than those three specified commands are used, or if any intermediate files are modified, the result is not FIPS validated.* "  </br> If I have to ask you an additional question, I have to customize source code of openssl 1.0.x vers. to be able to integrate at Broker's legacy code(C based), and so when can I integrate FIPS Object Module to the source code? </br> Thanks for your helping, so appreciate to you again.

Comment: @korayguney: I think the FIPS Guide you cite is pretty clear here: if you modify the OpenSSL code then the result cannot be FIPS compliant any more. It does not matter if you modify it before or after you've applied the FIPS module. But anyway - this is a different question from your original one so if you want to discuss this deeper please create a new question and not continue in the comments here.